# QGIS HTML in print composer, how to use "if" statement when building an expression?

Tags: qgis, printing, html, atlas, if-statement

I'm trying to include some images in a map layout to make an atlas.

Currently I'm using the following HTML

`<img src=[%"FILEPATH_TO_IMAGE"%] height="400"/>`

However, there are some situations where the atlas feature does not have a file path associated with it.
In this case it's shown as a question-mark instead.

Is there a way to add an IF-statement in the form of: IF filepath does not exist, nothing happens (do not execute the HTML img-block).

Comment: How do you hand the filepath to the expression?

Answer (score 1):

you could try it with a Case-Expression (assuming you have an attribute column with your picture path):

```
CASE 
WHEN length("Field_with_path")=0 THEN '' 
WHEN length("Field_with_path")>0 THEN 'do something fancy'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with conditionals inside the HTML code, for instance using `alt=''` or an `onerror` tag. There are various alternatives, not in the QGIS context but general HTML, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995080/html-if-image-is-not-found

(I haven't actually tried this - away from my QGIS computer right now)